# How to bypass test coverage for external/dependency vue components?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, code-coverage, vue-test-utils

We have two vue3 projects. Project 1 has some components that use components from Project 2 as imported dependencies.

In Project 1, `MyComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <Project2Modal> Some html here </Project2Modal>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

import Project2Modal from 'project2/components/Project2Modal.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Project2Modal,
  },
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    ...
});
</script>
```

The problem we are having is that, when we try to test (using `jest` and `vue-test-utils`) those components from Project 1, the test coverage also includes coverage for the Project 2 dependency components (as demonstrated by the "uncovered" lines not being part of the `MyComponent.vue` file at all). Which makes the overall Project 1 test coverage way lower than it should be (it becomes 100% when we remove the `project2Modal` component from the template).

Project 1 `test --coverage`

```
------------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                                      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                                 |   96.96 |    90.04 |   96.07 |   97.05 |                   
 src                                      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  globals.js                              |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 src/components                           |   73.33 |       25 |      20 |   73.33 |                   
  MyComponent.vue                         |   73.33 |       25 |      20 |   73.33 | 118-136
```

How can we tell jest from Project 1 to bypass the test coverage for Project 2 components? (as those are already tested in Project 2).

In `jest.config.js` we have already tried forbidding getting coverage from Project 2 but this does nothing:

```
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '!<rootDir>/node-modules/project2',
  ],
```

We haven't found any related or already asked question for this problem, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Istanbul? It looks like you might be able to achieve what you want in a couple of ways with that, or you can amend your Jest setup in the package.json directly.

I used [this article](https://codewithhugo.com/jest-exclude-coverage/) when I was ignoring imported files when testing for coverage and it got me sorted.

Comment: We are indeed using Instanbul but unfortunately none of those solutions from the article work for us :( Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: @CatDev dang it. I know it seems weird but have you tried adding an empty new line between the Istanbul comment and the import line in the component you shared in the OP, I've seen that work occasionally?

Comment: And not exactly friendly or pretty, but if you're using Istanbul in project2 then you could try put this line at the top of the Project2Modal.vue file - `/* istanbul ignore file */`

Comment: I just tried adding the newline between the import and the comment but it still doesn't do anything.
If we add that ignore file comment on that file then it will be ignored from the test coverage for Project 2 which is already tested so we can't do that :(